# how to tackle a problem with ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, community

i personally have been on and off with ubuntu since... 9.04 i belive.

now i'd like to stay with ubuntu for good. i have settled in with 12.10.

the thing is, im not an expert in this field, i do not have professional knowledge on source coding not to mention programming language (basic c is all i've got, except all the pythons i played with in my calculator when i was in high school...)

ubuntu is always developing and there have always been problems and solvings people worked out. and i am more than greatful for this huge community.

now i want to contribute. not in a sence that i would donate money, but actually problem solving. I have been having so many stability issues with ubuntu which is why i have been on and off with it.

i am wondering how and where i should start with tackling problems if i encounter one.

any advice please, would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This isn't really a question. Hang around here and answer questions where you are able. That would be a start to contributing.

Comment: Just a note on your choice of 12.10.  While 12.10 desktop is the latest stable release, its support will run out when 14.10 is released in less than two years.  You will have to update before then. 12.04 is an LTS release and will be supported until April 2017, and might be a better choice if you want an Ubuntu to "stay" with long term.

Answer (score 1):

Some people at Ubuntu actually have thought about that before and compiled a [list](http://www.ubuntu.com/community/get-involved) with how you can get involved in Ubuntu. This should be a good starting point to figure out, how exactly you would want to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

As far as knowing how to answer questions here, hang around for a little while and you will get to know not only the common solutions to common problems, but you will get a better understanding of how the problem solving process works.  To start with, use Google to find solutions to questions asked and compare them to answers that are given by others.  If it turns out that your research suggests a better answer than those already given then write an answer (not just a link) with the information.  Links to the information you found are fine, as long as you write up the answer yourself as well. (Links may disappear, leaving only your work for others that may come along.)